# IndexError Finding number of distinct values per class in Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I need to:

1. Find distinct values in each col in data frame then
2. Calculate frequency of them in each col and finally
3. Calculate no. of each distinct value in each column according to each class in data frame

```
import pandas as pd

data= pd.read_csv("C://Users//dataset//diabetes//diabetes.csv")

for col in data:
distinct_values=data[col].unique()

print distinct_values

for i in distinct_values:

    d=data.loc[data[col]==i]

    s1=d.groupby('class')[col].value_counts()[1].to_dict()

    s2=d.groupby('class')[col].value_counts()[2].to_dict()
```

But I have this error:

```
IndexError: index out of bounds

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-c5f4eb95987b>", line 1, in <module>
    debugfile('C:/Users/El-Amir Tech/Desktop/1.py', wdir='C:/Users/El-Amir Tech/Desktop')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 902, in debugfile
    debugger.run("runfile(%r, args=%r, wdir=%r)" % (filename, args, wdir))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\bdb.py", line 400, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "c:/users/el-amir tech/desktop/1.py", line 37, in <module>
    s2=d.groupby('diabetes')[col].value_counts()[2].to_dict()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 813, in get_value
    return libindex.get_value_at(s, k)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 65, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at (pandas\_libs\index.c:3565)

  File "pandas\_libs\src\util.pxd", line 69, in util.get_value_at (pandas\_libs\index.c:20186)

IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Comment: can you attach diabetes.csv

Comment: Without seeing the data this may be very difficult to get help on here.  Try using the debug function in Spyder (comes with Anaconda) and "Step" through your code until you find the error.  Here is a video on how to do this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SNaW1nt6j0

Comment: Diabetes data set link... https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/pima+indians+diabetes